# How to use custom user access control?

Tags: oracle-apex

I created custom authentication, every user from table users can login to the app.
How can I restrict user if user has READ_ONLY role, that can only read app page and can't edit?

I have tables:

```
           users(id, login_name, password),
           roles(role_id, rname), 
           user_roles-junction table (users-roles), 
           privileges(id, pname),  
           role_privileges-junction table (roles and privleges)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control what a user can do in the app through authorisation schemes. It is not possible to make an entire app read only, so what you could to is the following. Suppose you have 2 authorisation schemas: READ_ONLY and EDIT. All the EDIT/SAVE/SUBMIT buttons and their corresponding page processes you then restrict to the edit authorization scheme. That way a user with READ_ONLY and not EDIT will only see the reports and forms but not be able to change any data.

Comment: how can I connect tables above with apex, and assign privileges through tables

Comment: Create procedures and functions which will enforce everything you want. Use them in Apex to create appropriate authorization schemes. Apply those schemes on pages/regions/buttons/wherever needed.